# Add Text file to assets folder after export apk file with C#

Tags: c#, android

Just assume some persons's information exist in Asp.net developed application.
and also another application have been written to display the data of mentioned persons for android(by Eclipse).
How could make change in "APK" file after adding data for new Person by Asp to get the data of mentioned person from website.
How mentioned person ID could be placed as text file in assets folder while APK SIGN dont interfere it.

I want have personal apk for each person and personal apk created(or modified) by Asp website(This APK contain a text file with MyPersonId and it added to ASSETS folder with C#).

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking for. Please edit the question and add more information, especially about the Android App.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can use the application settings.You can store the persons data in the Application settings and load new person data from Asp.NET web service and write them to the settings again.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same, and i'm almost there.

Basically i used MIT AppInventor to create an APK for Android. On it, i created a TXT file in the assets folder. The MIT AppInventor compiled the code to create the APK file for distribution.

I than placed the APK in a folder, owned by an ASP.net page. The goal would be to open the APK file (as a Zip, currently using the ZipSharpLib), locate the "info.txt" on the assets folder, and replace it for another.

My problem so far is on the "re-pack" ou "re-compress" the copy of the file; android is not recognizing it as a valid APK.

So, up to the "decompress" the APK, run every entry, locating the one that is the asset to replace i'm good (just use ZipSharpLib, classes ZipFile and ZipEntry - they show you how on their site). But on the "compress" a new changed file, i'm failing.

Comment: i'll edit this answer once i figure out the last part

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of things you would need help of a decompilation and recompilation tool such as [ApkTool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool). You can't just zip back the files and hope android recognize zip format as an apk format immediately. There's a signing process included to make it a "real apk" again